# Can you unequip an inventory bag?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I have four standard 4-slot bags equipped, but now I have crafted an 8-slot storage box and want to use that.  I'm afraid there is no way to un-equip one of those standard bags... am I right ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can unequip bags simply by dragging and dropping them into one of your other bags or dragging another bag on top of it. However, **you need to make sure the bag you are trying to unequip is empty**, otherwise this will not work.

Answer (score 3):

Just drag the bag icon to a free slot in your inventory. It worked for me.

Also, you can substitute one container with another. Drag & drop the new box on top of the bag you want to substitute, just like you could do when you equip a new piece of armor over an old one.